# Blazor WASM SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Categories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, blazor-webassembly, sql-server-express

Sorry for posting what might seem a duplicate but please bear with me!

My first time working on a Blazor .NET Core applications with Entity Framework. My project is based of **Thomas Beck**'s [project](https://github.com/thbst16/dotnet-blazor-crud) from Github, I have modified according to my requirements.

I have two entities with many to many relationship:

```
public class Hymn
{
    public int HymnId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public string Scale { get; set; }
    public string Lyrics { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleting { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
}
```

and

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Hymn> Hymns { get; set; } = new List<Hymn>();
}
```

I use entity framework commands to create and update the table and even populate them with data in my SqlExpress databse.

[image]

Now, I have a .Razor page where I want to add new Hymn. Each hymn can have one or more categories represented as a list of checkboxes.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Categories:</label>
        @foreach (var category in Categories)
        {

            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="@category.CategoryId" @onchange="@(e => HandleCategoryChange(category))" />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="@category.CategoryId">
                    @category.CategoryName
                </label>
            </div>
        }
</div>
```

and the code block

```
    @code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Page { get; set; } = "1";
    private Hymn Hymn = new Hymn();
    public ICollection<Category> Categories = new List<Category>();
    [Parameter]
    public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Create Hymn";
    [Parameter]
    public bool loading {get; set;} = false;
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Categories = await CategoryService.GetCategories(null, Page);
    }

    async Task CreateHymn()
    {
        loading = true;
        try
        {
            Hymn.Categories = Categories.Where(c => c.IsSelected).ToList();

            await HymnService.AddHymn(Hymn);

            AlertService.Success("Hymn added successfully", keepAfterRouteChange: true);
            if (PageHistoryState.CanGoBack())
            {
                navManager.NavigateTo(PageHistoryState.GetGoBackPage());
            }
            else
            {
                navManager.NavigateTo("/hymn/1");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AlertService.Error(ex.Message);
            loading = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    void ToggleCategorySelection(Category category)
    {
        category.IsSelected = !category.IsSelected;
    }
}
```

Category and Hymn have their own services taking care of all DB operations.

All of the above works find as long as I don't choose any category, when I choose one or more categories I get the mentioned exception.

The categories are pre-generated in the Categories table and are the only categories I want to use, I don't want to create new ones each time I create a new Hymn.

[image]

I understand the cause of the problem (or at least I think I do), which is that SQL does not like that the CategoryId for the Category entity is being set "somewhere", which I'm not trying to do as far as I'm concerned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible your Hymn domain object is defining a new category from an old category thus you’re getting the SQL server error.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Would you like to post your contribution here sir? So I mark it as the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One thing I have done to debug situations like this is to set a breakpoint in the EF code and capture the SQL statement (in the console - enable logging to do this) that gets sent - then copy it and run it in SSMS and many times the error pops right out - worth a try.

Comment: I will definitely give it a try. Thanks!